# How can i find the compatible databases for python 2.2

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, mongodb

For some weird reason one of our app run in python 2.2 and no way we can upgrade it.

So i have to run a script to export data from that app using python 2.2 .

Is there any way i can find  which MongoDB or SQLite or Mysql version is compatible with python 2.2 and its db drivers are available.

Comment: Python 2.2 came out in 2002 and Python 2.3 in 2003. MongoDB began in 2007. It's unlikely that someone would develop a MongoDB-driver for Python 2.2. (Though not impossible; just because it's not _meant_ for 2.2, doesn't mean it won't work there.) And out of curiosity: what kind of weird system is that where you can't upgrade python but install a realatively new nosql-database?

Comment: Why not export your data into CSV file. Then import the data into other database?

Comment: We can upgrade , but if we upgrade the app will not work!! we are using another ancient Vignette

Comment: I am embarrassed to say that i cant export db for some other weird reason. my managers was  embarrassed to say that to me too

Comment: If you can't make backups, you have bigger problems.